# if and else in python lambda expression

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda

Please help me to understand how this works. Output is 4

```
a=4
b=7

x=lambda: a if 1 else b
lambda x: 'big' if x > 100 else 'small'
print(x())
```

Comment: whats your question ?
is it about if - else or about lambda expression ?

Comment: You should read about the lambda function.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's remove this line as it doesn't do anything:

```
lambda x: 'big' if x > 100 else 'small'
```

This `lambda` expression is defined but never called.  The fact that it's argument is also called `x` has nothing to do with the rest of the code.

Let's look at what remains:

```
a = 4
b = 7

x = lambda: a if 1 else b

print(x())
```

Here `x` becomes a function as it contains code.  The `lambda` form can only contain expressions, not statements, so it has to use the expression form of `if` which is backward looking:

> true-result if condition else false-result

In this case the condition is `1`, which is always true, so the result of the function `x()` is always the value of `a`, assigned to 4 earlier in the code.  Effectively, `x()` acts like:

```
def x():
    return a
```

Understanding the differences between *expressions* and *statements* is key to understanding code like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` is always equals to 4, as it takes no arguments and `if 1` is always `True`.
Then you have lambda expression that's not assigned to any variable, neither used elsewhere.
Eventualy, you print out `x`, which is always `4` as I said above.

P.S. I strongly suggest you to read [Using lambda Functions](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html) from `Dive into Python`

Answer (score 0):

Let me translate that for you.

You assign to `x` a `lambda` function with no arguments. Because 1 always evaluates as `true`, you always return the externally defined variable `a`, which evaluates as 4. 
Then, you create a lambda function with one argument `x`, which you don't assign to a variable/access name, so it is lost forever. 
Then, you call function `x`, which always returns `a`. Output is 4.